# SQL Query Problem

Tags: sql

When I am doing SQL Query on the database then all the months that are there in database and all the values corresponding to that particular month will be summed up in the Amount Column.
Suppose this is a table

```
Month     Category   Amount  Year
January   Rent       12      2011 
March     Food       13      2011
January   Gas        14      2011
May       Enter      15      2011
March     General    16      2011
```

So I written the query to sum all the values of a particular month by using this:-

```
"SELECT Month, SUM(Amount) AS OrderTotal FROM budget1 WHERE year="2011" GROUP BY month "
```

So I got the result as this:-

```
Month       Amount
January      26
March       29
May       15
```

But I want is that it should show all the months from January to December and Value of 0 infront of those month which are not there in the database like this for above example.

```
Month         Amount
January        26
February       0 
March         29
April          0
May         15
June           0
July           0
August         0
September      0
October        0
November       0
December       0
```

Any help will be appreciated..!!

Comment: Does the sort matter?  In your example of the desired answer they are sorted.

Comment: Yes sort matters actually.. And all the months are inserted into database dynamically through some form and corresponding values also.

Comment: To get the months in some particular order, you can declare the `Month` field as an Enum (my guess its is currently a varchar or some such). To get all the months, you could do one of two things: (1) postprocess the data in your code, or (2) somehow make your database aware that it should report all 12 months. I recommend (1) -- it is easier and makes much more sense from a design perspective. To achieve (2), one approach would be to put the month names into a separate table, and perform a `join` on that table. It's a bit of a hack, but it would do what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a month table, with your months and the sort order.  Then left join your month column to the month column in your data table.  That will get you the zeros.

So your table will look like

```
Month       Sort
======================
January     1
February    2
March       3
etc.
```

You can create the table by using [Create Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx), following by [Insert Scripts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE #months (month VARCHAR(50), sort INT);

INSERT INTO #months VALUES ('January', 1);

INSERT INTO #months VALUES ('February', 2);
etc.
```

Then

```
SELECT m.Month, SUM(Amount) AS OrderTotal 
FROM #months m LEFT OUTER JOIN budget1 on m.Month = budget1.Month
WHERE year=2011 
GROUP BY m.Month
ORDER BY m.Sort
```

Comment: I am not creating table by myself.. Tables are created dynamically and months are inserted by user. So if particular month was not inserted then it should show zero for that.

Comment: Why couldn't you still have this static table to join your dynamic table against?

Comment: Can you explain with the example here as I am confuse how can I combine using join the two tables and how it will work as you said

Answer (score 4):

Create a table with all months Jan-Dec, call it Months.  Just a single column with the names or add an extra integer for sort order (I usually call this the ordinal column), as follows:

```
create table months (
    month varchar(20),
    ordinal
);

insert into months values ('January', 1);
insert into months values ('February', 2);
insert into months values ('March', 3);
...
insert into months values ('December', 12);
```

The specific syntax may depend upon your database platform.  Then, depending upon your database:

```
SELECT months.Month, SUM(Amount) AS OrderTotal 
FROM months 
left join budget1
on months.month = budget1.Month
WHERE year="2011" or year is null
GROUP BY months.month, months.ordinal
ORDER by month.ordinal
```

You'll need to convert SUM(Amount) to 0 when null.  The specific function or approach to do this depends upon your database platform, or you can just do it in the code that is interpreting the results.

Comment: Actually all the months are inserted into database dynamically through some form and corresponding values also.

Comment: @Rahian Jamal,  you are missing the point.  The table Month proposed by squawknull is a table of constants of sorts, it is created once and only contains all the Months, independently of the way the Month field is populated along with the rest of the record, in the budget1 table.  This trick allows the query to supply a Month entry even when there were no records in budget1 table for said month.

Comment: @Rahian Jamal, an additional suggestion is to add a number column in the Month table, with values 1 thru 12 for Jan thru Dec respectively, as this column would help you to provide a sorting order.  In the absence of an ORDER BY clause in the query, SQL doesn't warranty a particular ordering.

Comment: I am confuse with your code. Table is not months, table is budget1 there is nothing like months. Can you explain it clearly. Sorry Now I got it what you are trying to say..!! Let me try this as you said.!!

Comment: Good suggestion mjv, I modified the answer as suggested.  Raihan, I'll try to clarify the answer.  You need to create a new table.

Comment: @squawknull :- I am trying this code as said by you but I am only getting the months that have the values in the database not the one that have zero values 'var mySQL = "SELECT months.Month, SUM(amount1) AS OrderTotal FROM months left join budget1 on months.Month = budget1.month WHERE year='"+abc1+"' GROUP BY months.Month, months.ordinal ORDER by months.ordinal";'

Comment: @squawknull:- now its working... That was my mistake.. So how can I convert null to zero.. Any suggestions?